# How to add a set of muffled data through pipe () -> tap ()?

Tags: angular, spring, date

It all started because of problems with the date (Date) why Angular showed me the date of the database with one day less. And in search of correcting that problem, I came to this:

#### clientes.component.ts

```js
 ClientesActualizado: cCliente[]; ----

 this.clienteService.getClientes(page).pipe(

        tap(response => {

    /*the content is converted to a Client list */
          (response.content as Cliente[]).forEach(cliente => {

    //THIS TO PROVE THAT ALL NAMES SHOW
            console.log(cliente.nombre);

    //CHANGING the date, adding one more day
            const createdAtCovert = moment(cliente.createAt).add(1, 'days');
            this.date = createdAtCovert.format('YYYY-MM-DD');


    //ADD IT BUT SEPARATELY, use the array for a single client, do not put them all at once.
              this.ClientesActualizado = [({id: cliente.id, nombre:cliente.nombre, apellido: cliente.apellido,
                email:cliente.email, createAt: this.date})];

            console.log( this.ClientesActualizado)
          });

        })
```

[image]

I wanted to add a new array with the muffled data I got from tap (response => {}), modifying the date, and then showing it in HTML. Please hope you can help me, or maybe there is another way to correct Angular's error of showing the date with one day less. It has been a very short time since I have been driving Spring and Angular

Comment: Can you help here and show how your API response looks like? It would be helpful to see how date looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting the date to appear in your HTML as UTC, you can use the Angular Date pipe with the UTC timezone:
`{{dateValue | date:'yyyy-MM-dd':'UTC'}}`
Otherwise, the date will be converted to local time when it's displayed.